# How to set a message to be unread/read using Gmail API using objective-C SDK?

Tags: ios, gmail, gmail-api

I wrote the following function to modify the message by marking it unread:

```
- (void)modifyMessageWithId:(NSString *)gmailMessageId
{
    __block GTLQueryGmail *query;
    query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesModify];
    query.identifier = gmailMessageId;
    query.addLabelIds = @[@"UNREAD"];

    [self.gmailService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLGmailMessage *result, NSError *error) {
        // Check result here
    }];
}
```

Then I checked the result and there's an error saying the id (which I think means the `query.identifier` I set) is an unknown field name. I also tried to set `query.messageId` instead and got a similar error:

> `(lldb) po error`
>
> `Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Unknown field name: id)" UserInfo=0xdd37e70 {error=Unknown field name: id, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0xdd37cd0: {message:"Unknown field name: id" code:400 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Unknown field name: id)}`

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this... same code and same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug; it is now fixed.

It is no longer necessary to use the strict = false workaround that was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24975490/3377170).

Answer (score 2):

Hi fatshu and Andy,

while we work on fixing the root issue, doing this should temporarily make it work:

```
query.urlQueryParameters[@"strict"] = @"false";
```

(right before your call to executeQuery).

Cheers and sorry for the inconvenience,

Jorge

EDIT: As user3377170 correctly points out, the bug is now fixed and the workaround isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: TY :) will give this a try tonight.

Comment: No problem; it was fun to debug :) In very few days it should be working without the need for this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is a bug in the Gmail API SDK.

Comment: Google's REST API for Gmail worked for me. Maybe you meant their iOS SDK?

Comment: @Sid yes, sorry I meant the api wrapper/sdk. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the Gmail REST API. I was able to use Google's APIs Explorer to mark an email as unread. The problem may be with their iOS SDK.

So, there is a way to do this but you might have to forego the iOS SDK and make a direct HTTP request to their REST API. Here is how you can do it:

Authorize your app via their [OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) and then send a POST request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{SOME_EMAIL_ADDRESS}/messages/{MESSAGE_ID}/modify?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

with the following POST request body:

```
{
 "addLabelIds": ["UNREAD"]
}
```

Please see their [API documentation on how to modify messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) for more details. I would suggest you try to use their APIs Explorer, just as I did, to see if it works for you or not.